# Why is this X.509 certificate considered invalid?

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, x509

I have a given certificate installed on my server. That certificate has valid dates, and seems perfectly valid in the Windows certificates MMC snap-in.

However, when I try to read the certificate, in order to use it in an HttpRequest, I can't find it. Here is the code used:

```
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly); X509Certificate2Collection col =
    store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "xxx", true);
```

`xxx` is the serial number; the argument `true` means "only valid certificates". The returned collection is empty.

The strange thing is that if I pass `false`, indicating invalid certificates are acceptable, the collection contains one element—the certificate with the specified serial number.

In conclusion: the certificate appears valid, but the `Find` method treats it as invalid! Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try verifying the certificate chain using the [X509Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.aspx) class. This can tell you exactly why the certificate isn't considered valid.

As erickson suggested, your X509Store may not have the trusted certificate from the CA in the chain. If you used OpenSSL or another tool to generate your own self-signed CA, you need to add the public certificate for that CA to the X509Store.

Comment: The chain certicates are present, but somehow were not accessible to this user. I used this sample code from MSDN to check the chain status: http://tinyurl.com/4wfnng . This code retruns different status depending on the user. I will try to reinstall the certificates. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Is the issuer's certificate present in the X509Store? A certificate is only valid if it's signed by someone you trust.

Is this a certificate from a real CA, or one that you signed yourself? Certificate signing tools often used by developers, like OpenSSL, don't add some important extensions by default.

Answer (score 3):

I believe x509 certs are tied to a particular user.  Could it be invalid because in the code you are accessing it as a different user than the one for which it was created?